# Oracle Database Alert log script error

Tags: linux, oracle, shell, sh

i wrote alert log script and some how this is not working and not throwing any error when i execute the script 
i am suspecting sed part is not working properly. could you please advice where i am doing wrong?

here is the piece of code

```
#!/bin/sh



## Heading #########################################################################################
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# script usage                                                                          #
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

_usage() {
  echo "Usage: $0 ORACLE_SID "
} # _usage

    ORACLE_SID="$1"
    setenv ()
    {
        eval "$1=$2"
        export "$1"
    } # setenv

    unsetenv ()
    {
        while [ $# -gt 0 ]
        do
            unset "$1"
            shift
        done
    } # unsetenv

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
   _usage
   exit 1
fi

Env=/u01/app/oracle/config
HN=`uname -n`
ERROR_FILE=/tmp/${ORACLE_SID}_error.log
HN=`hostname`
DBA_MAIL="oracle.mail@company"
DBA_PAGE=""



#+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|  get oracle environment variables from our common env dir                            |
#+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

if [ -r $Env/${ORACLE_SID}.env ]
then
    . $Env/${ORACLE_SID}.env
else
    ORACLE_SID=""
fi

#+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|  just checking for Oracle Env variables for connecting database                      |
#+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

if [ "$ORACLE_SID" = "" ]
then
        echo "ORACLE_SID is invalid"
        exit 1
fi
if [ "$ORACLE_HOME" = "" ]
then
        echo "The environment variable ORACLE_HOME must be set"
        exit 1
fi
if [ "$ORACLE_BASE" = "" ]
then
        echo "The environment variable ORACLE_BASE must be set"
        exit 1
fi

_AlertLogLoc ()
{
ALERTLOG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s "/as sysdba" << EOF
set head off pause off term on feed off timing off
select value from v\\$parameter where name like 'background_dump_dest';
exit;
EOF`
}
_AlertLogLoc
echo $ALERTLOG
export ALERTLOG


if [ -f $ALERTLOG/alert_${ORACLE_SID}.log ]; then
        echo "Found Database Alert log"
else
        echo "Alert log not found .. exit from  script"
fi

if [ -f $ALERTLOG/alert_${ORACLE_SID}.skip ]; then
        echo " ORACLE_SID skip error file found"
        SKIP_ERR=`cat $ALERTLOG/alert_$ORACLE_SID.skip|xargs|sed -e 's/ /|/g'`
        echo $SKIP_ERR
else
        echo "No errors will be excluded"
fi
REC_CUR_ALSIZE=/oraworkspace/OSE/logs/alert_${ORACLE_SID}.size  # file to record current alert log lines
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# let Capture ORA- error from the alert log                                                               #
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

if [ -f $REC_CUR_ALSIZE ]; then
        ALSIZE=`cat $REC_CUR_ALSIZE|sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'`
                ALSIZE=`expr $ALSIZE + 1`
else
ALSIZE=0
fi


if [ $ALSIZE -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "PROBABLY RUNNUNG THE SCRIPT FIRST TIME"
        sed -n  $ALSIZE',$p' $ALERTLOG/alert_${ORACLE_SID}.log |egrep -v "$SKIP_ERR"|grep -i 'ORA-' > /tmp/${ORACLE_SID}_error.log
        #`wc -l $ALERTLOG/alert_${ORACLE_SID}.log > $REC_CUR_ALSIZE
        cat $ALERTLOG/alert_${ORACLE_SID}.log|wc -l > /oraworkspace/OSE/logs/alert_${ORACLE_SID}.size
        #ALSIZE=`cat $ALERTLOG/alert_${ORACLE_SID}.log |wc -l`
else
        sed -n  ${ALSIZE}',$p'  $ALERTLOG/alert_${ORACLE_SID}.log |egrep -v "$SKIP_ERR"|grep -i 'ORA-' > /tmp/${ORACLE_SID}_error.log
        #wc -l $ALERTLOG/alert_${ORACLE_SID}.log >> $REC_CUR_ALSIZE
        cat $ALERTLOG/alert_${ORACLE_SID}.log |wc -l > /oraworkspace/OSE/logs/alert_${ORACLE_SID}.size
fi



#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Notify if any errors are found                                                                          #
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

ERR_CNT=`cat /tmp/${ORACLE_SID}_error.log |wc -l`

if [ $ERR_CNT -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Errors found in the alert log. send email notification"
        mailx -s "${HN}:${ORACLE_SID} ORA error Found in the alert log" ${DBA_MAIL} < $ERROR_FILE
        #mailx -s "${HN}:${ORACLE_SID} ORA error Found in the alert log" ${DBA_MAIL}  < $ERROR_FILE
else
        echo " No errors found in the alert log"
fi
```

Comment: What output *do* you get?

Answer (score 0):

If `$ALERTLOG/alert_$ORACLE_SID.skip` doesn't exist or is empty (around line 94), the `egrep -v "$SKIP_ERR"` will exclude *all* lines from the `sed` output, so it will not have a chance to see any remaining `ORA-` errors.

```
ALSIZE=1
SKIP_ERR=""
sed -n  $ALSIZE',$p' $ALERTLOG/alert_${ORACLE_SID}.log |\
  egrep -v "$SKIP_ERR"|wc -l

0

SKIP_ERR="dummy"
sed -n  $ALSIZE',$p' $ALERTLOG/alert_${ORACLE_SID}.log |\
  egrep -v "$SKIP_ERR"|wc -l

15165
```

So you need to set your `SKIP_ERR` to something when it's not set or empty (if your skip file is empty). You haven't said if that is the case or shown the script output, but it seems to work apart from that.

Also not that if `ALSIZE` is zero `sed` isn't happy, at least in RHEL 5:

```
ALSIZE=0
SKIP_ERR="dummy"
sed -n  $ALSIZE',$p' $ALERTLOG/alert_${ORACLE_SID}.log |\
  egrep -v "$SKIP_ERR"|wc -l

sed: -e expression #1, char 4: invalid usage of line address 0
0
```

And when you test that the file exists at line 91, you show a message stating that and suggesting you'll stop there, but there is no `exit` after line 94; doesn't seem to be relevant here but seems like an oversight?